# Cannot find symbol File

Tags: java

I'm working on a course project and using this code block my professor gave us to, one, get all files from the current directory and, two, to find which files are in the .dat format. Here is the code block:

```
// Get all files from directory
File curDir = new File(".");
String[] fileNames = curDir.list();
ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();

// Find files which may have data. (aka, are in the .dat format)
for (String s:fileNames)
    if (s.endsWith(".dat"))
        data.add(s);
```

However, when I try to compile and test my program, I get this error message in response:

```
Prog2.java:11: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class File
location: class Prog2
   File curDir = new File(".");
   ^
Prog2.java:11: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class File
location: class Prog2
   File curDir = new File(".");
                     ^
```

I admittedly have minimal experience with the `File` class, so it might be my fault entirely, but what's up with this?

Comment: Did you import File class? Try adding 'import java.io.File'.

Answer (score 14):

Import the `File` class from the `java.io.File` package

i.e.

```
import java.io.File;
```

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/io/File.html) is documentation for `java.io.File` and a [brief explanation of the `File` class](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/java_io_file.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Just add the following statement before the class definition:

```
import java.io.File;
```

If you use IDE, like Eclipse, JDeveloper, NetBeans, etc. it can automatilly add the `import` statement for you.

Comment: Yep, that did it! That was definitely my fault, I didn't realize it needed an import statement as well. I'm on the vi editor rather than an IDE.

Comment: Then you have to be extremely careful what classes you use. The IDEs provide the developers with great help for this.

Answer (score 1):

I think Naveen and Poodle have it right with the need to import the File class

```
import java.io.File;
```

Here is another method of getting .dat files that helped me, just FYI =)

It's a general file filtering method that works nicely:

```
String[] fileList;
File mPath = new File("YOUR_DIRECTORY");

FilenameFilter filter = new FilenameFilter() {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File dir, String filename) {
        return filename.contains(".dat");
        // you can add multiple conditions for the filer here
    }
};

fileList = mPath.list(filter);
if (fileList == null) {
    //handle no files of type .dat
}
```

As I said in the comments, you can add multiple conditions to the filter to get specific files.  Again, just FYI.